# How do I typecast over a typeclass constrainted parameter?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I want to write a function that works for all my custom datatypes (that are part of my custom typeclass), but each datatype has their own implementation. For example:

```
getValue :: Ent entity => entity -> Float
getValue (Player position _) = doA position
getValue (Enemy position) = doB position
```

This however gives me the following error:

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type ‘entity’ with actual type ‘Player’  
> ‘entity’ is a rigid type variable bound by  
>   the type signature for:  
>    getValue :: forall entity. Ent entity => entity -> Float
> ```

How can I write a function that has a unique implementation for all the types of my typeclass?

Comment: You need a typeclass for the ad-hoc polymorphism of `getValue`. You thus add `getValue` to the `Ent` class, and define instances for `getValue` in the instance clause of the `Player`, `Enemy`, etc.

Comment: Note that you can't do this in the way you've written it because anybody could add a new instance of `Ent` later on.  That's why you have to do this in the type class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this *in* the type class, making `getValue` its *method*:

```
class Ent a where
   getValue :: a -> Float

instance Ent Player where
   getValue (Player p _) = doA p

instance Ent Enemy where
   getValue (Enemy e) = doB e
```

Now `getValue :: Ent a => a -> Float` which is the same thing as you wanted.

Type variables' names don't count, up to consistent renaming.

Comment: Ah yes. I was already reading online about instances online, but seeing this written out made me fully understand it. Thanks! I don't understand your your last sentence though. Type variables' names?

Comment: it means `Ent a => a -> Float` and `Ent entity => entity -> Float` is the same.